# Google YouTube API v3 Throwing 503 Backend Error

Tags: python, google-api

I'm working on an application that scrapes songs from certain websites and programmatically "Likes" them on youtube through Google's Youtube API. To obtain the video IDs that I'm looking for, I perform a google search with the artist and song title and parse through the results. This process works fine and returns valid video IDs (I've tested them manually). Where I run into issues is the code I have for "Like"ing something based on a video ID, which is essentially copied directly from google's YouTube API Python example:

```
def likeVideo(youtube, video_id):
    channels_list_response = youtube.channels().list(
      mine=True,
      part="contentDetails"
    ).execute()

    # Adding a video as a favorite or to the watch later list is done via the
    # same basic process. Just read the list id of the corresponding playlist
    # instead of "likes" as we're doing here.
    liked_list_id = channels_list_response["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["likes"]

    body = dict(
      snippet=dict(
        playlistId=liked_list_id,
        resourceId=dict(
          kind="youtube#video",
          videoId=video_id
        )
      )
    )
    youtube.playlistItems().insert(
      part=",".join(body.keys()),
      body=body
    ).execute()

    print "%s has been liked." % video_id
```

However, my app is throwing this error:

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?alt=json&part=snippet returned "Backend Error">
```

Searching through google dev forums reveals that this might be a server side issue on Google's part, but I'm not sure for my specific situation. Anyone see what might be wrong?

EDIT: I've been using this app in the past few days and it seems to be working somewhat decently; few 503 errors... However, at this point it's usually doing only one API request per session. When I first ran into the error, it was doing a batch of about 6. Is there something that happens when doing batch requests that I should account for?

Answer (score 4):

It won't let me comment on your question, I don't really consider this an answers but perhaps just something to consider. Sometime ago I was working on a project where I had a CSV list full of youtube video URLs. I wanted to put the Title of the video next to the URL in my CSV list. Given that the title of the page was the title of the video, I utilized URLLIB to grab the page from the URL in the list, grab the title, put it into my list and loop through the next one, and the next one, etc etc. Anyways, I only got partial results! Only something like half of them worked. Well it turns out I was hitting youtube too fast with URLLIB and their servers must of been throttling me back or something, I implemented a 5-15 second timer and got varying results. I did 15secs between each video and I was able to get every page title. Now granted your using youtube API which I know nothing about, but perhaps calls to youtube data through their API is throttled as well somehow? I'm just spit balling here, and sorry for posting this as answer, but I can't seem to find the comment button!

Edit - To try and make this seem more like an answer, try utilizing the time module to sleep between API calls.

```
while 0 == 0
  likeVideo(youtube, video_id)
  time.sleep(15)
```

Hope this helps, or atleast someone else does. Good luck!